# Stripe not registering new logs

Tags: vue.js, stripe-payments

Hello there I have implemented stripe api on my local. After submission I am able to generate my token the issue is that I get no new [logs](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments)  on test when submitted the card data (I used sample card data ie:"4242..").

"TestData" Cardholder name does not appear on stripe.com/test/payments

I have followed this implementation from
[github](https://github.com/fromAtoB/vue-stripe-elements) and based the tutorial on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BB-nXTPyNtE&t=1714s) since I am also using vuejs.(see 38:09). His submission on stripe works.

[image]

So far the only thing I was able to register on the stripe logs was the checkout from Stripe.

Here is a snippet from my method

```
            pay () {

                let options = {
                    name: this.card_details.cardholder_name,
                }

                createToken(options).then(response => {
                    var form = document.getElementById('stripe-form2')
                    var hiddenInput =  document.createElement('input')
                    hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
                    hiddenInput.setAttribute('name','stripeToken')
                    hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', response.token.id)
                    form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
                    form.submit.preventDefault;

                    this.catchfields(this.card_details.cardholder_name)
                    
                    this.successMsg = 'Information Saved'
                    this.errorMsg2 = ''
                    console.log(response.token)
                    billingService.saveStripeToken(response.token)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response)
                    })

                }).catch( error => {

                    this.catchfields(this.card_details.cardholder_name)
                    console.log(error)
                })
            },
```

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the Stripe logs?

Comment: Do you mean that the checkout is failing, and the webhook is not firing? There is no actual successful checkout logged?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you're expecting to see. It sounds like the "logs" you're seeing are the successful payments in test mode, but it's not clear from your question what else you're expecting to see or what has changed.

Comment: @taintedzodiac the url I am pointing to under the logs is https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/payments. The new details that I have submitted on stripe does not appear on that link. How was Andre (creator of video) able to achieve this?